# Can I convert Selenium Window Handle to Windows 7 Window Handle?

Tags: python, winapi, selenium

I'd like to use Win32APIs to controll Selenium on Windows 7 with python. So I need to know how to get Windows Handle of the window created through Selenium.

When I executed current_window_handle method of Selenium, I got text ID.

```
>>> import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
>>> browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>>> browser.current_window_handle
u'{9f16832b-7313-4ff4-afff-e31448d901c5}'
```

It certainly is different from the Windows Handle because the Windows Handle must be int value.
Does anybody know how to convert the string id to Windows Handle? Or a good practice to get Window Handle using python selenium?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to control win32api to set window to the foreground and etc. Now I just use GetWindowHandle instead of Selenium WIndow Handle.

Comment: Enumerate the main windows looking for ff